# Identifying certain polygon from overlapping set

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, overlapping-features

To clean up a large shapefile, I am looking for a way to do the following:

- I have the ID of many polygons which need getting rid of stored in a list. These polygons are villages and a second shapefile has the watersheds to each of these, and they overlap.If I delete a village polygon I need the data assigned to it to be appended to the next village downstream. The next village downstream will belong to the next larger overlapping watershed, or the 2nd smallest one to overlap with the original village. The villages and watersheds are linked by an ID number.
- First step would be: identify the ID of the 2nd smallest *entirely overlapping* polygon from the watershed shapefile which overlaps with the village identified in the list.

The "Identify" tool looks like it could do the trick but I can't find the script to it, does that exist for Python?

If anyone with experience in python for ArcGIS (ArcMap 10.2 Advanced license) or have tips do let me know!

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, but if you've calculated the area of all "villages", then you can spatial join them to the "watersheds" using the "within" match option. Then it's a matter of sorting and deleting the second smallest. Is your question simply, "how to select the second smallest polygon from a group of polygons"?

Comment: Not quite, I'll try to clarify. It's more that for some villages, the watershed polygon is erroneous, so I'd like to delete that watershed and assign the socio-economic data of the village to the next village downstream. The next village downstream would be the one attached to the next bigger watershed that overlaps with the original village and watershed (ie the second smallest of all overlapping ones).

Comment: To clarify this I think it may be better to edit a picture into your question along with the additional words you placed into your comment.

Comment: I suspect that the focus of this question should be how "to identify the ID of the 2nd smallest entirely overlapping polygon from a different shapefile which overlaps with the first".  If you can clarify just that part in this question then I suspect it will become easy to answer, and then if you are still stuck on any remaining parts they can be researched/asked separately.

Comment: thanks @PolyGeo , I was having trouble putting words to it. Updating question now.

Comment: I *think* your second dot point may be the focus of your question but having that illustrated with a picture would I think make it much clearer.  I think the first dot point may be distracting, and making this look harder than it need be, perhaps leave it out, and use for a later question - any answer(s) to this one may make that unnecessary to ask.